Route planning tools for covering a set of roads?
I'm trying to find a set of bike routes to cover a set of road segments, given that I can only ride a certain distance in one ride. Is there a route planning tool that will help with this?
What I'm trying to do right now is ride all the roads in my neighborhood. But such a tool would be helpful for e.g. riding all the trails in a park, or doing a wandrer.earth-style challenge.
This problem, finding an optimal set of routes to cover a set of road segments, is the capacitated arc routing problem. It's known to be difficult for computers to solve. But it seems like software could still do better than me looking at a map and drawing waypoints.
The Strava routes tool doesn't offer a feature like this. I've tried a few other tools such as Komoot but I haven't found any that do it. Is there anything out there? How would you solve this problem?

This might be better on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?  Despite being related to cycling, it is more about software for routing.

This is the classic “traveling salesman problem” with the added twist of a limit on the total distance traveled. Reading up on the TSP might help.

CARP merely is TSP with capacity constraints (i.e. take an impossible problem and make it harder).  Question is close to asking for recommendations, which is OT. Will wait and see if answers manage to avoid being recommendations only.

Regarding the question being OT - there are many "Related" questions on this site with answers that are software suggestions (use Strava route planning/use Google Maps/etc.). So it didn't seem unreasonable to ask this question here.

I do not know any software that would do this, though I think it would be fun (and useful also with Veloviewer’s explorer tiles). I have few ideas how this could be done, but parts of this answer will definitely go outside the topics of bicycles and more into cstheory or cs stacks.

I do not think it’s actually too bad an idea to do this by hand. I’m mostly familiar with Komoot for this kind of routing, and with it, I would start doing round trips. The first one would go to the farthest point I’d like to visit, and then stay as far as possible until returning. The next one would go to the farthest not-yet-visited point, etc. With cities, I’d probably do bunch of zig-zagging to cover many small streets; with trails that’s usually not necessary or even possible. I would assume that if the number of roads/trails one wants to cover is (clearly) less than one hundred, this should be doable with some effort. Paid version of Komoot has multi-day-trip planner, that could help, but I haven’t used it, so I can’t say for sure. And I’m sure other planners could be used instead of Komoot. The most useful feature would be the ability to see the already-planned routes to remember which roads/trails are already covered.

Considering this as an algorithmic problem (and now we’re getting away from bicycles, and I’m going to use term ‘cycle’ to mean a round trip in a graph-like data structure, but bear with me), this is (almost) the length-constrained lane covering problem (see Immorlica, Mahdian & Mirrokni, 2005). Notice that this is not travelling salesman or variant thereof, as one can cover the same edges (and vertices) many times. That said, the problem still seems to be NP-hard and Immorlica et al. give an (1 + ln 2) approximation algorithm for it. There are two caveats, however. (1) Their algorithm is not very practical (more on that later). (2) They consider cycles that can start anywhere, whereas in this application, we probably want to have all cycles start from (and end to) the same point (home, hotel, parking place, …).
The main idea of Immorlica et al.’s algorithm is actually easy. It’s a greedy algorithm that always finds the most cost-effective cycle (round-trip), marks the newly-visited roads visited, and repeats until all roads are covered. The cost-effectiveness of a cycle is simply the fraction of the length of new roads in the cycle to the total length of the cycle. The hard part is to find the most cost-effective cycle, given the maximum length constraint. Unfortunately the algorithm proposed by Immorlica et al. for that problem does not seem like anybody would want to implement it (for the curious: the description of it is most of the proof of Theorem 6.1 of the above paper, with a footnote giving links to further details).

My first proposal on how to do this by hand was a “human approximation” of the algorithm by Immorlica et al. One can do everything by computer by replacing the proposed complex cycle-finding algorithm with some greedy heuristic that always starts form the same point (say, always take the edge (i.e. road/trail) that gives you the most cost-effective route when you consider the shortest way home from the end of that edge). For someone who knows their way around, say, Python, this should not be too hard to implement using NetworkX and OSMnx. In fact, it sounds like a funny little holiday project, if only I’d have time for funny little holiday projects.

Thanks, your suggestion of going to the farthest point and of zigzagging is a good one. I think the "farthest point" idea can be generalized a bit, basically by considering how easy it is to add a segment to other routes. Segments near the start point are low-cost to add to many different routes, while segments far away are high-cost to add to most routes. If a segment is relatively easy to add to the current route compared to adding it to most other routes, then add it to this one. This strategy would lead to covering entire far-away neighborhoods in one ride.
